# field with a button in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bounded DataGridView. How can I add a button in one field with data? I will attach a screenshot of how I see it. Do you have any recommendations on this? [image: Example]

it's WinForms and I think that I need to write a custom column type.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create custom column:

   ```
   class TextAndButtonControl : UserControl
   {
       private TextBox textbox1;
       private Button button1;

   public TextAndButtonControl()
   {
       this.textbox1 = new TextBox();
       this.Controls.Add(this.textbox1);            
       this.button1 = new Button();
       this.Controls.Add(this.button1);            
       this.RenderControl();
       this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
   }

   void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Hi");
   }

   public string Text
   {
       get { return this.textbox1.Text; }
       set { this.textbox1.Text = value; }
   }

   public string ButtonText
   {
       get { return this.button1.Text; }
       set { this.button1.Text = value; }
   }

   public void RenderControl()
   {
       this.textbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
       this.textbox1.Width = 2 * this.Width / 3;
       this.textbox1.Height = this.Height;            
       this.button1.Location = new Point(2 * this.Width / 3, 0);
       this.button1.Width = this.Width / 3;
       this.button1.Height = this.Height;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Add the control in the following way

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       TextAndButtonControl bcol = new TextAndButtonControl();
       bcol.Text = "Button Column ";
       bcol.ButtonText = "Click Me";
       bcol.Name = "btnClickMe";
       bcol.RenderControl();
       dgMainGrid.Controls.Add(bcol);
   }
   ```

Comment: Not exactly, I need the field to display data (they are different) and button at once (see the picture I posted).

Comment: Updated the answer, the location of the column depends on you, please use the solution to suit your needs.

Comment: You will have to change the RenderControl() method - set the location, width and height properties to suit your needs.

Comment: thank you Raviraj, I change some code and now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standard `DataGridViewColumn` subclasses provide what you're after.

It can be done, though: you will have to create your own custom `Control` (I guess a `TextBox` with a `Button` right next to it), and the appropriate`DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewCell` subclasses to host your custom control.

Follow [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells) for further details.

Of course, the alternative would be using third-party, smarter grids.

Comment: I find this, but can't change, I'm not Expert (( Can you pleas help me? ((

Comment: @DavidMamulashvili Then I'm afraid this task might be a bit beyond your current skill levels :/ Diving into it would make you learn a lot, though. Another way would be to settle for a different UI than the one you're after, but how that would look like entirely depends on what you need that button for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DataGridViewButtonColumn-Type (Or if you just want a single Cell as Button -> DataGridViewButtonCell-Type).

You could create the DataGridButtonColumn and then add it to your DataGridView:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn tempBtnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
tempBtnColumn.HeaderText = "Button";
tempBtnColumn.Text = "Button-Text";
tempBtnColumn.Name = "Button-Name";
tempBtnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

Grid.Columns.Add(tempBtnColumn);
//or if you want a specified position for the Grid:
Grid.Columns.Insert(0, tempBtnColumn);
```

**Update**

Here is an update, you could give the ButtonCell the Value you want and then read that with CurrentCell.Value (here is a example, hope it's understandable):

```
private void ButtonCellWithValue()
{
    DataGridViewButtonCell dgvbc = new DataGridViewButtonCell();

    dgvbc.Value = "1";

    DataGridViewRow dgvr = new DataGridViewRow();

    dgvr.Cells.Add(dgvbc);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvr);

    dgvbc = new DataGridViewButtonCell();

    dgvbc.Value = "2";

    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1] = dgvbc;

    GridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
}

void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value == "1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Super");
    }
    else if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value == "2")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Better");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, I need the field to display data (they are different) and button at once (see the picture I posted).

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot @RavirajPalvankar.

If somebody will need, I will write the code here, because cann't write it to Ravuraj's comment, because it's long:

Use the class as Raviraj write:

```
class TextAndButtonControl : UserControl
    {
        private TextBox textbox1;
        private Button button1;

        public TextAndButtonControl()
        {
            this.textbox1 = new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(this.textbox1);
            this.button1 = new Button();
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.renderControl();
            this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }


        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click! The value is:" + this.Text);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this.textbox1.Text; }
            set { this.textbox1.Text = value; }
        }

        public string ButtonText
        {
            get { return this.button1.Text; }
            set { this.button1.Text = value; }
        }

        public void renderControl()
        {
            this.textbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.textbox1.Width = 2 * this.Width / 3;
            this.textbox1.Height = this.Height;
            this.button1.Location = new Point(2 * this.Width / 3, 0);
            this.button1.Width = this.Width / 3;
            this.button1.Height = this.Height;
        }
    }
```

then in main Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("col1");
    dt.Columns.Add("col2");
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("col1" + j.ToString(), "col2" + j.ToString());
    }

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 150;
    this.txbtnControl = new TextAndButtonControl();
    this.txbtnControl.Visible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(this.txbtnControl);

    //Handle the cellbeginEdit event to show the usercontrol in the cell while editing
    this.dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);
}

TextAndButtonControl txbtnControl;

void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
        this.txbtnControl.Location = rect.Location;
        this.txbtnControl.Size = rect.Size;
        this.txbtnControl.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        this.txbtnControl.ButtonText = "...";
        this.txbtnControl.renderControl();
        this.txbtnControl.Visible = true;
    }
}
```